# No of character limit in "Web Content Display" feature of Liferay tool

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is there any default limit on the no of characters we can add in "Web Content Display" of Liferay tool ? If there is any limit , which setting to modify to increase the no of characters we can add.

Answer (score 1):

As such there is no limit on character count for Web Content.

AFAIK, there is no settings available to limit character count, but you can use  [Marketplace App](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/41824486) which facilitates this.